# The eigenvalue for ST and TS when the vector space is finite and when it is infinite

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> For $S,T\in L(V)$. It is true that ST and TS have the same eigenvalue.

Suppose $STv=\lambda v$. Then $TS(Tv)=T\lambda v=\lambda Tv$.

Thus, ST and TS have the same eigenvalue. However, what about in infinite-dimensional vector space $V$?

Suppose $v\in V$ and $v=(x_1,x_2,...)$ and $ Tv=(0,x_1,x_2,...)$. $ Sv=(x_2,x_3,...)$

Thus， $STv=(x_1,x_2,...)$   $TSv=(0,x_2,x_3,...)$

Suppose $ST$ has eigenvector $\lambda_1$ and $TS$ has eigenvector $\lambda_2$

Then it's clear thet $\lambda_1=1$.

For $\lambda_2$，suppose $\lambda_2=\lambda_1=1$.

$TSv=(0,x_2,x_3,...)= \lambda_2(x_1,x_2,...)=(x_1,x_2,...)$. Hence $x_1=0$

Then the eigenvetor is $(0,x_2,...)$ and eigenvalue for $TS$ and $ST$ are 1

There must be something wrong since I know this won't hold when the vector space is infinite, so what's going wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: My confusion is that I know for finite-dimensional vector spaces ST and TS should have the same eigenvalues, but this won't necessarily hold when the vector space becomes infinite. I know there is a standard counter-example that is using the "left-move" linear map S and "right-move" linear map T that are specified in my proof. However, I can't really understand this counter example

Comment: In your example, vectors of the form $(x_1, 0, 0, \ldots)$ are $0$-eigenvectors for $TS$, but $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $ST$.

Comment: Probably this is exactly where I am confused. In the example, shouldn't the vector in the form $(0,x_2,...), (x_2,x_3,...\in \mathbb F$) is the eigenvector for both ST and TS, with both of them having eigenvalue 1?

Comment: You showed that $ST$ and $TS$ both have $1$ as an eigenvector. But while $ST$ has no other eigenvalues, $TS$ also has $0$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you very much